# Merge different .pptx files into one

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am trying to merge different .pptx files into one. That is, I have templates for each slide, I am able to modify MergeBlock and MergeField but I don't know how to join all the .pptx files into one.
Please someone who has done it and can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OpenTBS cannot combine two PPTX (nore DOCX, nore XLSX) for now. This is a complicated operation because it implies to retrieve all styles, charts, images, objects from the source document; and to place them correctly inside the target document.